# Android App successfully published on Google Play but not searchable in Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, playback

I have published my Android app to Google Play. It is showing status published, but when I search in the Google Play store app, it's not found. I tried it in multiple devices, none is showing my app. If I search in the Google Play website with the app name, it is showing on the website but not in any mobile,

When I open app link in my mobile **"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=XXXXX.XXX"**, it redirects to the app and it got installed on mobile. What is going wrong?

My package name is XXXXX.XXX, is that fine? Or should it be like com.abc.pqr?

I have used below Permission in my app, is there anything related to permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- if you want to load images from a file OR from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: If you are searching your app using package name then you must have to use complete package name which is specified in gradle file.

Comment: can you share your package name so we all can check the availability of your app on play store ?

Comment: Hi @Ketan make sure you short and long app description contains app name , and also it take some time to update in play store search

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time to index it after publishing app. Until that you might not find it in the search.

There are also some cases in that you can't see application in search:

- It doesn't match the device you use to search for it.
- It doesn't match he country you're in.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to any `permission`. This is true that after publishing app it takes sometime to search or find out.

But you need to add `keywords` in your developer console from where you have published your app. Also there have some suggestions for you. Check this out -

1. **Keyword Research** & Strategy with Keyword Planner Usually helps to create a semantic core with relevant keywords
2. **Reviews & Updates Monitor** for App Store & Google Play has Suggestion & Search tool that helps to see which keywords people use in every country. Also it helps to track your position for keywords.
3. Also you can contact to a **ASO Service provider** to reach further.

This might be helpful for you. Give it to a try.